# python string splitting

Tags: python, string, split

I have an input string like this: `a1b2c30d40` and I want to tokenize the string to: `a, 1, b, 2, c, 30, d, 40`.

I know I can read each character one by one and keep track of the previous character to determine if I should tokenize it or not (2 digits in a row means don't tokenize it) but is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', 'a1b2c30d40')
['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '30', 'd', '40', '']
```

On the pattern: as the comment says, `\d` means "match one digit", `+` is a modifier that means "match one or more", so `\d+` means "match as much digits as possible". This is put into a group `()`, so the entire pattern in context of `re.split` means "split this string using as much digits as possible as the separator, additionally capturing matched separators into the result". If you'd omit the group, you'd get `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '']`.

Comment: Umm I don't understand regex very well. Do you mind putting some explanation of the (\d+) pattern?

Comment: It splits on numbers/consecutive digits (`\d` is 0-9, `+` is one or more).

Comment: +1: but I think it would be better to use a raw string for the regexp

Comment: @6502: it matters only if there are any Python-interpreted escapes (e.g. `\n` or `\t`) in the pattern (to avoid escaping the `\\` in them).

Comment: @Piotr: I know... but I think your answer would be more instructive with a raw string for two reasons: 1) in my experience the fact that Python leaves the backslash in the string if the escaped code is not valid is often surprising: open("c:\zer\woob.dat") works and open("c:\temp\buf.dat") doesn't 2) there are much more special chars than \t and \n and specifically '\b' is one of them and r'\b' is instead special for a regexp. By using that fancy `r'(\d+)'` may be the reader will take the time to read about the escaping problem...

Comment: @Piotr: There is no reason why you should not use a raw string ALWAYS in a regex.